# How do I cycle through several sounds using one action?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

Right now I have a single sound playing from one action, button press, accelerometer, etc..

I would like to know how I can cycle through several sounds (I'm using 3 sounds for my project) from a single action that the user initiates.

I am currently using the code shown below and it serves it's purpose for playing a single sound for each user action. I have not used NSArray in a project before, so if your including it please include any details.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Jet.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
        else 
            [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Do you want to play that in loop or you want to use this single action to play different sounds??

Comment: I have 3 sounds, I have one button, I want a different sound to play each time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using 3 sounds then you can get away with just using a C array of `NSString`'s but if you need a dynamic amount of sounds then you should change to using an `NSArray`

```
// .m
NSString *MySounds[3] = {
    @"sound1.wav",
    @"sound2.wav",
    @"sound3.wav",
};

@implementation ...
```

Then in your method you need to add a little extra logic

```
- (void)playSound;
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], [self nextSoundName]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if (audioPlayer == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    } else {
        [audioPlayer play];
    }
}

- (NSString *)nextSoundName;
{
    static NSInteger currentIndex = -1;

    if (++currentIndex > 2) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    return MySounds[currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: Xcode is whining about the nextSoundName, its throwing up two errors for that. Also,error ( Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void' is disallowed with ARC. )

Comment: I've updated the `NSURL` construction as I wrote it i the browser (poorly). What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)playSound:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], [MySounds objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]]];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    else 
        [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Here you can use single action buttons for all buttons. Just you need to do is set the tags to button. Use array as described by Paul